# webdriver.io's browser.deleteCookie() doesn't delete all cookies

Tags: selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I use a cucumber/webdriver.io test environment and need to delete all cookies at one place. I use

```
    console.log(await browser.getCookie());
    await browser.deleteCookie();
    console.log(await browser.getCookie());
```

Console shows

> [ { domain: 'jira-xxxxxx',
>       httpOnly: false,
>       name: 'atlassian.xsrf.token',
>       path: '/',
>       secure: true,
>       value: 'xxx' },   { domain: 'jira-xxxxxxx',
>       httpOnly: true,
>       name: 'JSESSIONID',
>       path: '/',
>       secure: true,
>       value: 'xxxxxx' } ]
>
> []

So it seems to clear out the cookies. But Chrome's cookie list still looks like:

[image: Chrome Cookie Settings / Full list]

Any idea why webdriver.io doesn't delete some cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies did not delete because those might be server-side only. As you can see the last console log shows httponly: true flag.